# Equivalent of sfDoctrineRoute in Symfony2

Tags: symfony1, symfony

In Symfony 1.x, there were routing objects which would simplify the retrieval of an entity or list of entities in your controller action... `sfDoctrineRoute` and `sfDoctrineRouteCollection`.

My question is, are there any equivalents for these in Symfony2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent in the Symfony routing.

But you can take a look at the ParamConverter system provided by the SensioFrameworkExtraBundle.

You'll find a description here: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html

Comment: cheers, I'll take a look. I'm really surprised that there is no equivalent given Symfony2's tighter integration with doctrine, maybe they will release it in a future point release

Comment: excellent, this is exactly what I was looking for and does mostly what `sfDoctrineRoute` did in symfony 1